# pagination for dynamic table in angularjs html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am new to angularjs. 
I want to add pagination to dynamically creating rows of table. after 3 rows added display pagination.
 when you click buy, it adds row but not paginating after 3 rows. I mentioned limit as 3 in controller ( script.js)
please check plunker demo here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/aViHHoqLBSSiIVMh2KkH?p=preview

```
`<tr ng-repeat="sum in priceSumRow | filter : paginate">`
buySellApp.controller('buySellCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.totalItems = $scope.priceSumRow.length;
 $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.numPerPage = 5;

  $scope.paginate = function(value) {
  var begin, end, index;
   begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
     end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    index = $scope.priceSumRow.indexOf(value);
   return (begin <= index && index < end);
 };
 }]);
```

Comment: And what is the problem that you want us to help you solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to correct in your code.

- You are defining the same controller `buySellCtrl` twice. once in your script.js and once in html itself, which is totally unnecessary.instead you can ,move the `paginate` code inside the `script.js`.
- `total-items` for pagination should the length of the array `priceSumRow` like `<pagination total-items="priceSumRow.length" ...` instead of  `<pagination total-items="totalItems.length" ...` which prevents a extra scope variable from the controller.
- `max-size="3"` for pagination defines the max limit for the records to be displayed in a current page & `items-per-page="numPerPage"` defines definite number for records in a page **but in your case you had defined `numPerPage` as 5**

---

*Note:I would suggest you to work in a strict mode `use strict;`, strict mode is a way to opt in to a restricted variant of JavaScript.*

> [MDN :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) Strict mode makes several changes to normal JavaScript semantics. First, strict mode eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by changing them to throw errors. Second, strict mode fixes mistakes that make it difficult for JavaScript engines to perform optimizations: strict mode code can sometimes be made to run faster than identical code that's not strict mode. Third, strict mode prohibits some syntax likely to be defined in future versions of ECMAScript.

[Working Demo @ Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yONXacSkLmk12OkgXZ7m?p=preview)

Comment: waw thanks.... its working as expected .. :)  you have corrected many errors in my demo...thanks a lot

Comment: Your welcome. Now can you close this question by ticking against the answer

Comment: check this help page, to know more on how to accept the answer and certain do's & dont's while doing the same.http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers