# Pagination with server side data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How to do a simple pagination in angularjs,I am getting the data in my controller from db and I want to show all data with pagination in angular?

Comment: it would be great if you provide some code Which you tried :)

Comment: Couple of days i answered a similar question, check here it has a live demo as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/36599342/1677272

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you, is a filter, that allows you to paginate the data on your controller.
https://github.com/svileng/ng-simplePagination

Answer (score 0):

I use the Pagination directive from UI Bootstrap
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

Here is a small code sample with a fake ajax call:

```
<uib-pagination items-per-page="3" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination-sm" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;" style="margin:0px;"  ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pagination>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/mqs6zS?p=preview